# convert 3d array in 2d array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array returned from function and it is like 
this is used to print a grid , but grid comes to be blank not even a single entry

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 47
                [name] => Test Product 1
                [description] => tesw
                [sku] => test050
                [price] => 125
                [quantity] => 12
                [status] => 1
                [created_at] => 2014-07-09 12:53:07
                [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 49
                [name] => Test Product 3
                [description] => 
                [sku] => test053
                [price] => 3600
                [quantity] => 56
                [status] => 2
                [created_at] => 2014-07-09 12:53:07
                [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 50
                [name] => Test Product 4
                [description] => test
                [sku] => test054
                [price] => 5450
                [quantity] => 5
                [status] => 1
                [created_at] => 2014-07-09 12:53:07
                [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            )
         )
       )
```

and it stored in $n, if i do

```
 foreach($n  as $reach)
        {
          echo $reach['product_id']
        }
```

it gives error .... Help ... Thanks in advance

Comment: `foreach($n[0] as $reach)` maybe ?

Comment: You should use an another foreach.

Comment: `$2Darr = $3Darr[0];`

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
 foreach($n  as $reach)
 {
    foreach($reach  as $a)
    {
       echo $a['product_id']
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

for fetching product_id from 3d array you can use this

```
foreach{$n as  value}
{
   foreach($value as value1)
   {
      foreach($value1 as value2)
      { 
            echo $a['product_id'];
      }
   }
}
```